# codeigniter - input form placeholder

Tags: codeigniter, text, input, helper

Hey all, how can I use the placeholder tag in CodeIgniter's `form_input()` helper function?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 16):

Do you mean the placeholder attribute (not tag)?  `form_input()` takes a third parameter with additional attributes.

```
$opts = 'placeholder="Username"';
form_input('username', '', $opts);
```

Or you can pass `form_input()` an array.

```
form_input(array(
  'name' => 'username',
  'value' => '',
  'placeholder' => 'Username',
));
```

[CodeIgniter Form Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: hm i cant get it to work :S is dont put a placeholder attribute on it

Answer (score 2):

The Codeigniter user guide linked to by Rocket indicates that attributes other than name and value are passed to form_input() as an array:

```
 $data = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
              'value'       => 'johndoe',
              'maxlength'   => '100',
  );

echo form_input($data);

// Would produce:

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="johndoe" maxlength="100" size="50" />
```

To expand on Rocket's answer, passing `'placeholder'=>'my_placeholder'` into that array should produce the placeholder attribute.

```
$data = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
              'value'       => 'johndoe',
              'maxlength'   => '100',
              'size'        => '50',
              'style'       => 'width:50%',
              'placeholder' => 'my_placeholder'
            );

echo form_input($data);
```

Keep in mind, the placeholder attr is very new and not supported in all browsers.  Check out [this article](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/form-input-placeholder-text/) at html center for html5, jQuery, and pure javascript ways to accomplish placeholders

Comment: It should produce the markup as suggested but it doesn't. May be the form helper function doesn't take new/custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter form placeholder for IE6, IE7 and IE8

```
echo form_input(array(
                'name' => 'stackoverflow',
                'value' => 'yourplaceholder',
                'placeholder' => 'yourplaceholder',
                'onclick' => 'if(this.value == \'yourplaceholder\') this.value = \'\'', //IE6 IE7 IE8
                'onblur' => 'if(this.value == \'\') this.value = \'yourplaceholder\''       //IE6 IE7 IE8
));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set placeholder like this

```
echo form_input('username','','placeholder=username');
```

this will look like this

```
<input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username'/>
```